# Debug a cURL request via PHPStorm debugger

Tags: php, curl, phpstorm

Inside a `Slave` site I have a script that performs a cURL request vs a server of mine (`Master`).
Locally, I have installed those two sites and I'd wish to debug what happens on `Master` when `Slave` tries to connect it.
Ideally, the perfect solution would be to attach my own request to PHPStorm debugger, so I can actually see what's going on.

I tried to start the debug, but then PHPStorm attaches to the calling script, and not the receiving site.

Do you have any suggestions on how can I actually debug it, without the need to rely on the good old `var_dump();die();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end of the day, PHPStorm relies on a cookie to attach to the incoming request.
By default, such cookie has the following value: `XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM`.

This means that you simply have to add the following line to your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM"));
```

and PHPStorm will "see" the incoming request, allowing you to debug it.

### Additional Tip

The previous trick works **everywhere**!
If you are trying to debug a cURL request from command line, once again you simply have to pass the cookie param and PHPStorm will attach to the request:

```
--cookie "XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM"
```